# Select nth-child(n) except the first matching child

Tags: html, css

I want to select all elements matching `nth-child(2n)` in a list except for the first matching element; for example...

```css
li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ul>
```

The result of this is that only Four, Six, Eight and Ten have a red background color.

I would like to know if there's a better way of expressing the CSS rules though, and if it's possible to express as a single rule:

```css
li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    background: none;
}
```

Can these be combined and still behave the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) to exclude the second nth child.

```css
li:nth-child(2n):not(:nth-child(2)) {
  background: red;
}
```

A better way would be to use the [`An+B` syntax for `:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation) to select every second child starting with the fourth child.

```css
li:nth-child(2n+4) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use `li:nth-child(2n + 4)`.
The format of the nth-child selector is `An+B`, where:

- A is an integer step size,
- B is an integer offset,
- n is all nonnegative integers, starting from 0.

```css
li:nth-child(2n + 4) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
  <li>Ten</li>
</ul>
```

In the format `(2n + 4)`, you're essentially starting from the fourth element (1 based index) and incrementing by two each time. So, 4, 6, 8, ...

Answer (score -1):

[CSS :nth-child Selectors](https://github.com/kalawaja/css-workout/blob/master/README.md#css-nth-child-selectors) -> You will find the answer below the README.

**NOTE:** Remember to scroll down to the bottom.

[css-nth-child-selectors codes](https://github.com/kalawaja/css-workout/tree/master/css-nth-child-selectors) -> There is also a view of the entire file, separated by header.

*I hope it will be useful for you.*

**The most appropriate for this situation would be the following:**

> ```css
> li:nth-child(2n+4) {
>     background: red;
> }
> ```